# Qt draw outline for multiline text

Tags: c++, qt, text, outline

`QPainterPath` can paint outline for the text

`QPainter` can draw multiline text

Is there any solution to make use of both of those features?

I also looked up for `QLabel` styles, and still didn't find anything outline-related.

Comment: you can create a new class that use its. Another option is try use QGraphicsItem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no such function exists in (at least, in Qt 5.15). What I did was wrote a function that takes a string and breaks it up into multiple lines, breaking on spaces or \r or \n. Loop over the string one word at a time, measuring it 'till it gets bigger than desired width (or you hit a line break), then back up one word, trunc any space, and call that one line. stick that into your vector of lines. repeat for each line. then in a separate function, you can draw each line one at a time, using stroke/fill from QPainterPath technique, advancing vertically by metrics.height() each line